# MongoDB return value from key in objects in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to match the value of address, from an object of arrays holding objects:

```
email: {
  verified: [
    {
      token: "gCCt1IUKXPfB4Lj3q_t2vDfiUhis87Ki7mVuR3YLDRD",
      address: "email@test.com",
      when: ISODate("2017-01-06T11:40:22.293Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

This didn't work:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({email: {$elemMatch: {address: email}}})
```

How can you do it when there's an array to traverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the array `verified` in your query, instead of `$elemMatch` you can just refer the object directly as shown below :

```
Meteor.users.findOne({"email.verified.address": email});
```